# Python Unit Testing Extensions

Tags: python, python-unittest

I'm relatively new to unittesting in python and find that some tasks are quite arduous and I've seen nicer packages in other languages.

I've been wondering if there are packages that help me for example with shortening validation of complex properties (of which I tend to have a lot) like below, or if there are none, is there any reason I should not consider writing them?

```
def test_lengthProperty(self):
    tester = new PropertyTester(instance.property)

    # assert raises TypeError
    tester = tester.withInstanceValidation('pass': (int, long, float))
    tester = telter.withInstanceValidation('fail': (str, complex, unicode, ...))

    # assert raises ValueError
    tester = tester.withMinValue({'pass': (0), 'fail':(-1)}) 
    tester = tester.withMaxValue({'pass': (100), 'fail': (101)})

    # assert the values are just stored not adjusted.
    tester = tester.setterEqualsGetter({'pass' : range(101)})
    tester.assertAll()


def test_dateProperty(self):
    # assert raises TypeError
    tester = tester.withSubclassValidation('pass': (datetime.date))
    tester = tester.withInstanceValidation('fail': (str, complex, unicode, ...))

    # Assert adjusts invalid dates
    tester = tester.assertAdjust(
        {'input' : date(2010, 31, 12), 
         'output': date(2011, 1,1)})
    tester.assertAll()
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're looking for here, but if you want to check that a call to a callable raises a `TypeError`, then use [`unittest.TestCase.assertRaises()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises) with `TypeError` as the first argument. The [`TestCase` class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase) provides a whole host of methods to check for and report failures.

Comment: Have you looked at [nose](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)? There are [plug-ins](https://nose-plugins.jottit.com/) for it as well. Or, if you do get into writing your own, nose might be the place to start.

Comment: I understand that I can do individual tests, but I'm looking after a shorthand, that allows me to use one line to make several assertions.

Comment: Looking at nose at the moment and it appears to cover many of my use cases. Thank you.